# Wordpress How to Check whether it is POST or PAGE

Tags: wordpress

How to check if an article is a post or a page in WordPress?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646736/check-is-custom-post-type

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use the [is_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_PAGE_Page) and [is_single()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Single_Post_Page) functions.

Comment: `is_single()` will also return true for custom post types, if you want to be 100% sure it's a post then use `is_singular('post')`

Answer (score 21):

You can also use [get_post_type()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/) function.

```
if (get_post_type() === 'post') {
    // POST
}

if (get_post_type() === 'page') {
    // PAGE
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're looping through a collection of posts/pages (say, on a search results page), then `is_single()` and `is_page()` won't be of any use.  In this situation, you could grab the global `$post` object (of type `WP_Post`) and examine the `$post->post_type` property.  Possible values include 'post' and 'page'.

Answer (score 1):

is_singular() returns true for a single post, page or attachment

Answer (score 1):

It's for developer, if you are not a developer you can also check current page type. You have to just inspect particular page and see body tag. If theme is build with basic WordPress rules then body tag have classes related to page or single page. These classes may b included the post type, template name, file name, page id and many more.

Comment: Looks like posts have a class "postid-CURRENT_POST_ID" and pages have a "page-id-CURRENT_PAGE_ID" on the body tag

Answer (score 0):

You mean that `is_single()` will return true if it is a post ? (not a page), am I right,

I like that, I think you wrong, because I have a plugin show some text on only post, I'm using `is_single()` but It also show on pages.

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: Use `is_singular('post')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you want y¡to know the page that list the posts , and you are using the posts page option in the configuration, You should use `is_home()`.